# Manejo de JSON con Python

Tags: python

Tengo un JSON super largo:

```
"items": [
            {
                "start_time": "0.64",
                "end_time": "0.85",
                "alternatives": [
                    {
                        "confidence": "0.462",
                        "content": "Mhm"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "pronunciation"
            },
            {
                "alternatives": [
                    {
                        "confidence": "0.0",
                        "content": "."
                    }
                ],
                "type": "punctuation"
            },
            {
                "start_time": "3.14",
                "end_time": "3.46",
                "alternatives": [
                    {
                        "confidence": "0.34",
                        "content": "Fresh"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "pronunciation"
            },
            ...
```

Mi código es:

```
with open("subtitulos/subtitulos-stt.json") as s:
    subtitulos = json.load(s)

for x in subtitulos["results"]["items"]:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
{'start_time': '225.99', 'end_time': '226.16', 'alternatives': [{'confidence': '0.571', 'content': 'hmm'}], 'type': 'pronunciation'}
{'alternatives': [{'confidence': '0.0', 'content': '.'}], 'type': 'punctuation'}
{'start_time': '226.54', 'end_time': '226.74', 'alternatives': [{'confidence': '0.758', 'content': 'Yeah'}], 'type': 'pronunciation'}
{'alternatives': [{'confidence': '0.0', 'content': ','}], 'type': 'punctuation'}
{'start_time': '228.24', 'end_time': '228.56', 'alternatives': [{'confidence': '0.289', 'content': 'chris'}], 'type': 'pronunciation'}
{'alternatives': [{'confidence': '0.0', 'content': '.'}], 'type': 'punctuation'}
```

Lo que quiero es poder obtener `content`, `start_time` y `end_time` individualmente. Con `subtitulos["results"]["items"]` solo me envia a todos, trato de colocar `subtitulos["results"]["items"]["start_time"]`

Sale el error de:`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Cuando le coloco un cero detras sale bien, pero, solo con el 0 (`subtitulos["results"]["items"][0]["start_time"]`), no muestra ni el 1, ni el 2.

Comment: te has preguntado por que si sucede con `subtitulos["results"]["items"][0]["start_time"]`?

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede porque como podrás darte cuenta items es un arreglo, no un objeto.
Para diferenciarlo, todo lo que empiece con corchetes cuadrados `[...]` es un arreglo y lo que empiece con corchetes `{...}` es un objeto (diccionario en python).

Diferencias.

Los objetos (diccionarios) son identificados a través de llaves

```
{
    'first_element': 'value_1' //elemento con llave `first_element`
    'second_element': 'value_2' //elemento con llave `second_element`
}
```

Los arreglos son identificados a través de posiciones

```
{
    'value_1' //elemento con posición `0`
    'value_2' //elemento con posición `1`
}
```

Sabiendo esto, si miras `items` notarás que es un arreglo. y solo funciona con `[0]` porque puede que solo haya un elemento dentro de ese arreglo

Comment: Los simbolos {} se llaman llaves.